# Detect and distinguish computer screens/monitor using Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, screen

I would like to implement a feature which could differentiate two screens extended by a computer(Pi4 in this case), so that I can render different UI in those screens as I want.

I have searched such a web api which is provided by Chrome Browser, however is it not enough for me to differentiate the screens in my case

```
window.screen.isExtended
```

Does any one has any advice or package which does provide such a feature? I know Node Webkit provides a similar api, but that does not seem to match my use case. Thanks!

Note: screens sizes and resolution are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the browser api which is released in 2020

```
window.getScreenDetails()
```

Which returns a promise to allow browser to read info about their screens.